# Create control at runtime

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I need to make a picturebox in VB.NET using code not the toolbox so it is not on my form just i draw it when I want it in code. Also No I don't want to use the: `visible = false` or `true`
I want to get a picturebox shown on a special position/x,y. Then I need it to execute a command once clicked. I am making a vb game and that is going to be pretty much the graphics layout.
If it may help i was pretty much thinking of it displaying a panel which is going to be made by using the draw features etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should help you to

- Create a PictureBox programmatically
- Position it on the form
- Set an image
- Add a click event handler
- Add it to the form

Make a new WinForms project and paste this code. No need to add any controls

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    addPictureBoxToForm()
End Sub

Private Sub addPictureBoxToForm()
    Dim pb As New PictureBox
    pb.Location = New Point(0, 0)
    pb.Image = Bitmap.FromFile("C:\test.png")
    AddHandler pb.Click, AddressOf PictureBox_Click
    Me.Controls.Add(pb)
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("The picture box was clicked")
End Sub
```